# Entity Framework: How to calculate the range of dates from other date range

Tags: android, sql, entity-framework, date

I am using an entity framework to calculate how many days from a date range with the target date range.

Let say I passed in a from date A to date B. In each row of the date I have previous log date and current log date. I want to see how many days was sitting inside between the previous log date and current log date.

My code i was currently written is:

```
var days = toDate.Subtract(fromDate).TotalDays;
            var usageLog = (from usageLogs in context.UsageLogs
                            where
                                (usageLogs.PreviousLogDate != null
                                    && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(usageLogs.CurrentServerLogDate) >= fromDate.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(usageLogs.PreviousLogDate) <= toDate.Date)) ||

                                (usageLogs.PreviousLogDate == null
                                    && ((DbFunctions.TruncateTime(usageLogs.CurrentServerLogDate) >= toDate.Date) && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(usageLogs.CurrentServerLogDate) >= fromDate.Date)))

                            select new
                            {
                                PackageName = usageLogs.PackageName,
                                estimateUsageCount = (double)usageLogs.UsageCount
                            });

            var statistics = (from usage in usageLog
                              group usage
                              by new
                              {
                                  usage.PackageName
                              }
                            into grp

                              select new
                              {
                                  PackageName = grp.Key.PackageName,
                                  UsageCount = grp.Sum(c => c.estimateUsageCount)
                              });

            return statistics.ToList();
        }
```

estimateUsageCount in the select statement is where I want to calculate the number of days sitting in between the previous and current log dates.
I am thinking to write function to do the job but don't know how to do it. I know the calculation is quite complicated. Does anyone give me an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select new
{
    PackageName = usageLogs.PackageName,
    estimateUsageCount = (usageLogs.CurrentServerLogs - usageLogs.PreviousServerLogs).Days
});
```

For the range between two dates, I found this excel formula:

```
=MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(MAX(Date1, Date2),MIN(dateA,dateA)))
```

that it can be translated into c# like this, using the ternary operator:

```
0 > ((date1 > date2 ? date1 : date2) - (dateA < dateB ? dateA : dateB)).Days ? 0 : ((date1 > date2 ? date1 : date2) - (dateA < dateB ? dateA : dateB)).Days
```

Comment: Thanks but this will get the  days different but which I really want was to have two set of date ranges and see how many days these two set of date ranges collide. Eg. Date1 to Date2 and DateA to DateB, and see the number of days they meet together

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. I've just edited my first response to include the range between two dates also. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I haven't got a chance to check yet.. I will try it later and tell you the result.